# Sqlite advanced search

Tags: android, database, sqlite, search

I'm developing an android application for a store, which provides many functions. One of these is a function that  allows the customer to search a product with some criteria (price,size,type... like in the picture ).

I guess I should work with `SqliteDatabase` , but I have no idea how I can make this multi-criteria search interface , so the user can query the database.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. after setup your database, you can use SQL queries and JOIN types with WHERE critaria and finally achive proper data, use Cursor class to iterate through results.

see:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0):

Before handling it, you should design your database properly.
Suppose, 
List of tables -

```
1) product_type(_id<should be primary key to link another table>, 
   type_id<integer>, type_name<text>
2) product_price(_id<should be primary key to link another table>, 
   type_id<integer>, price<double>
3) product_type_size(_id<should be primary key to link another table>, type_id<integer>, size<text>
```

And create views as your requirement - 
product_search(join your table properly)
And run your queries as requirement and match with the value of the view.

Go ahead--